# How to count occurrences in sql

Tags: sql

I would like to count how many times an id is present in a table, then print the title associated with this id from another table (next to the amount of occurrences). I also want to only return the top 10 in descending order.

I could only manage to return the total number of occurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT b.title, b.book_id,
       COUNT(*)
FROM books b INNER JOIN
     students_books sb
     ON b.book_id = sb.book_id
GROUP BY b.title, b.book_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I also added table aliases.  These generally make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: @BalázsVigváry . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?